# What is 'Elective Application Form'?

Tags: american-english, british-english, finance

I understand what application form is but how is it used with elective?
this phrase is from the financial area

Answer (score 0):

"Elective" implies that it is optional. In this case, it could mean that either the act of applying or the form itself is optional.

Alternatively, it could be that the application form is for an elective subject matter.